# using a function to sort odd and even numbers Javascript

Tags: javascript

Hi everyone I am trying to make a function to sort the odd and even numbers of an array and then display the total of each to my webpage. I don't get any response when I run my code. Could anyone tell me if they see something wrong I don't? Thanks ahead of time.
    var numList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

```
function numberTally(numList){ 

var evenTotal = 0;
var oddTotal = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < numList.length; i++) {

    if (i % 2) {  // i is odd

        oddTotal += numList[i];
        // or oddTotal = oddTotal + numList[i];

    }
    else (i % 3){  // i is even

        evenTotal += numList[i];



}
}

alert(oddTotal);
return evenTotal;

}
```

Comment: Your `else` statement doesn't need a condition.

Comment: Especially not `i % 3` which indicates whether a number is evenly divisible by 3, so might be odd or even (6, 9, 12, 15).

Comment: I suggest you get in the habit of indenting your code properly. It will make your life and everyone else's easier. Choose a good editor and it will do much of the work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function numberTally(numList){ 
    var evenTotal = 0;
    var oddTotal = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < numList.length; i++) {
    if (i % 2) {  // i is odd
        oddTotal += numList[i];
    }
    else {  // i is even
        evenTotal += numList[i];

    }
  }

  alert(oddTotal);
  return evenTotal;
}
```